# Why Date comparison is showing weird behavior in javascript?

Tags: javascript, performance, date

When I'm working with date comparison in javascript, in the browser console I did perform the following operations.

`new Date() >= new Date()` returned **true**

`new Date() <= new Date()` returned **true**

this looked good as I thought both are equal, if I was correct then

`new Date() == new Date()` should returns **true**

Interestingly it returned **false**. Then I performed below operations as well

`new Date() > new Date()` returned **false**

`new Date() < new Date()` returned **false**

`new Date() != new Date()` returns **true**

which was also fine with my assumption.

If both the ***new Date()*** s were returning same time then  **==** should return **true** along with the **>= and <=**, other wise either of **> or <** should return **ture** as **!=** returning **true**.

Following table consists expected results and actual results for different cases.

[image]

Why is the **ACTUAL** results column not following any of its preceding columns?

Comment: [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects). Dates are probably not an exception.

Comment: with those operators when you apply on Date object , you invoke to cast at integer ( similar with +new Date() that mean time in unix format - timestamp)

Comment: When you are performing the `==` comparison, you are actually asking "are these variables referencing the same object", which is `false`. All other comparisons work on the timestamp within the objects.

Comment: forget about == case, what about remaining cases? if results are random, why results are consistent?

Comment: The comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`) coerce Dates to their time value, whereas the equality operators (`==`, `===`, `!=`, `!==`) do not. In the second case you're comparing objects which are never equal.

Comment: you can also use `valueOf()` `d1.valueOf() == d2.valueOf()` where d1 and d2 are date objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Date.getTime` to compare the timestamp, otherwise you are simply comparing the objects, which we know aren't the same.

```js
var d1 = new Date(),
  d2 = new Date();

function fullCompare(a, b) {
  console.log(a == b, a <= b, a >= b, a < b, a > b);
}
fullCompare(d1, d2);
fullCompare(d1.getTime(), d2.getTime());
```

Comment: okay, then. I have one doubt, while comparing as object, == is false,  >= is true so  > should return true right?

Comment: @sitchie `>=` and `>` compares the inner timestamp as milliseconds since 1970, however and `>=` is `same value or higher than`, which returns true since both dates holds the same timestamp millisecond count. `>` on the other hand is `Higher than` comparison, which is false because they contain the **same** value.

Answer (score 3):

Check for equality like you're doing compares the *references* to the objects. To compare the actual values of the objects themselves, the most common practice is to call [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) method, which will return the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

Therefore, the following code will return `true`:

```
(new Date()).getTime() == (new Date()).getTime()
```

Comment: and then you are comparing the values with *millisecond* precision. @sitchie, do you want that precision?